# Julia - many allocation to browse an array in struct

Tags: arrays, struct, julia, allocation

I'm currently struggling with a weird behaviour of Julia.
I'm browsing through an array, and whether the array is inside a struct or not Julia doesn't behave the same.

There is many allocations that seem pointless in the case of an array inside a struct. To be specific there is as many more allocations as the size of the array.

Here's a code to replicate this problem :

```
function test1()
    a = ones(Float32, 256)

    for i = 1:256
        a[i]
    end
end

struct X
    mat
end

function test2()
    a = X(ones(Float32, 256))

    for i = 1:256
        a.mat[i]
    end
end

function main()
    test1()
    test2()

    @time test1()
    @time test2()
end

main()
```

And the output I get :

```
0.000002 seconds (1 allocation: 1.141 KiB)
0.000012 seconds (257 allocations: 5.141 KiB)
```

At first I thought it was a type problem, but I don't force it and the type isn't different after the loop.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the type of `mat` in your `struct`. Otherwise, your functions using `X` will not specialize and be optimized enough.

> Fields with no type annotation default to Any, and can accordingly
>   hold any type of value.
>   https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Composite-Types-1

Changing your struct definition to

```
struct X
    mat::Vector{Float32}
end
```

will solve the problem.
The results now are:

```
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 1.141 KiB)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 1.141 KiB)
```

You could actually see the effect through `@code_warntype` macro if you change one thing in your code.

```
for i = 1:256
    a.mat[i]
end
```

This part is not really doing much. To see the effect with `@code_warntype` change this line in your old code to

```
for i = 1:256
    a.mat[i] += 1.
end
```

The result of `@code_warntype` will give `Any` in red color which you should usually avoid. The reason is the type of `mat` is not known at compile time.

```
> @code_warntype test2() # your test2() with old X def
Body::Nothing
1 ─ %1  = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float32,1}, svec(Any, Int64), :(:ccall), 2, Array{Float32,1}, 256, 256))::Array{Float32,1}
│   %2  = invoke Base.fill!(%1::Array{Float32,1}, 1.0f0::Float32)::Array{Float32,1}
└──       goto #7 if not true
2 ┄ %4  = φ (#1 => 1, #6 => %14)::Int64
│   %5  = φ (#1 => 1, #6 => %15)::Int64
│   %6  = (Base.getindex)(%2, %4)::Any <------ See here
│   %7  = (%6 + 1.0)::Any
│         (Base.setindex!)(%2, %7, %4)
│   %9  = (%5 === 256)::Bool
└──       goto #4 if not %9
3 ─       goto #5
4 ─ %12 = (Base.add_int)(%5, 1)::Int64
└──       goto #5
5 ┄ %14 = φ (#4 => %12)::Int64
│   %15 = φ (#4 => %12)::Int64
│   %16 = φ (#3 => true, #4 => false)::Bool
│   %17 = (Base.not_int)(%16)::Bool
└──       goto #7 if not %17
6 ─       goto #2
7 ┄       return
```

Now with the new definition of `X`, you will see in th result of `@code_warntype` every type is inferred.

You may want to use [Parametric Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Parametric-Types-1) if you want `X.mat` to hold other types of `Vector`s or values. With parametric types, the compiler will still be able to optimize your functions since the type will be known during compilation. I would really recommend you to read the relevant manual entry for [types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/i) and [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Type-declarations-1).

Answer (score 4):

1. Never use abstract types in struct definitions. In your example Julia needs to store variable pointers instead of just values and hence the speed degradation.
   Instead use parametric types:

```
julia> struct X{T}
           mat::T
           end

julia> X{Float64}.(1:3)
5-element Array{X{Float64},1}:
 X{Float64}(1.0)
 X{Float64}(2.0)
 X{Float64}(3.0)
```

2. If unsure, consider using `@code_warntype` macro to see where the Julia compiler can not properly identify types.